# Hadoop FS: Is it normal to have modification time disparity with a file and its direct parent directory?

Tags: hadoop, filesystems

I have a test that puts file x into directory d in Hadoop FS. When I query the last modification time using Hadoop FS, I get a ~1-second disparity among results from d and x. Is this an expected behavior? If so, why?

[This is](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) the API I use with function `getModificationTime()` for both directory and file.

Comment: How long does it take to write the file?

Comment: Test file takes about 20-30ms to put.

Comment: I guess its the elapsed time between step #2 and #6 in the write path from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anatomy-of-file-read-and-write-in-hdfs/.

Comment: This might be the cause. Because of the granularity of timestamp which is 1 seconds according to [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/filesystem/introduction.html), it might be rounding to the next second when timestamp passes 0.5 seconds mark. I will try writing a large file and let you know if this is the case.